# How to split table cells in Open Xml?

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a document with a table. I need to be able to add columns to a specific row, while maintaining the original table width.

Essentially I need to SPLIT table cells. How can I do this using open xml for a word document?
I tried

```
                    var tc = new TableCell();
                    tc.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Hi"))));
                    row.Append(tc);
```

I tried just adding more cells, however it acts as new column and increases the size of the table.

Comment: I was hoping for an answer that doesn't involve "lel, use a table that has them split already".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create a table in microsoft word and split cell there. Now open your word document in OpenXML SDK Development Tool which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124). If you look at the relevent cell in OpenXML, you will find the answer to your problem. Just copy code from OpenXML and make any necessory changes according to your requirements.